# R shiny: Read file interactivity (data frame)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list of files in a directory and I want to display the information of each one in a graphic through R shinny. I use the list.files function then use the variable i to do a looping in the files. Using shiny, I would use i as an interactive variable. So I tried something like that:

```
Server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data=reactive({
data=read.table(list.files(directory)[input$i])
data
})

output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(data()["variable1"],data()["variable2"]])
})

UI.R

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
 sidebarPanel(
numericInput("i", "Indice:",
                min = 1, max = length(list.files(directory)), value = 1)

              )
 mainPanel(
   plotOutput("Plot")
    )
))
```

It is working for i=1, but when i choose another i values it stops working (the screen becomes grey). I believe the error is in the form I'm using the data frame, someone please could help me?

Thank you

Comment: Is there also an error thrown in `R` when the screen of the application goes grey? I say that because I see that you, also, `print` the data every time the `input$i` changes (correct me if I'm wrong). Is `data` loaded and shown in `R` as it should be every time?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Now it is working. Actually, I dont know what was wrong. I added the function "Observe" to update some fields of my plot, I think it is working now because of that.